# How to create a 'glow' effect on a Textbox in Typescript?

Tags: css, textbox, typescript, devextreme

I have recently installed DevExtreme (from the Dev Express website) as I was looking for a way to create a single solution for multiple mobile devices (this software allows that). Having created a 'Basic' Typescript project, I feel quite the idiot for not being able to get it to work!

**Below shows something similar to the desired effect:**

[image: Text input, where the focused textbox 'glows']

However, I am having some difficulty replicating this for some of the devices. For example, the windows Phone does this automatically, whereas the IOS device doesn't, and remains 'normal'. :(

I followed the advise [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22018433/3436942), and copied everything, but *still* the textbox refuses to 'glow' for me!

**My script:**

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#glow-trigger").on('click', function (e) {
            var glower = $('.glow');
            window.setInterval(function () {
                glower.toggleClass('active');
            }, 1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**My css for this:**

```
.glow {
    background-color: #ccc;
    border: 1px solid transparent;    
    -webkit-transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
       -moz-transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
            transition: border 0.1s linear, box-shadow 0.1s linear;
}

.glow.active {
    border-color: blue;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
            box-shadow: 0 0 5px blue;
}
```

**The 'practise' HTML:**

```
 <div class="home-view" data-options="dxContent : { targetPlaceholder: 'content' } ">
        <br />
        <p class="hovertest">
            <button id="myButton" onclick="sayHello()"> this is a button</button>
        </p>
        <br />
        <h1>this is a heading</h1>
        <br />
       <h2>another heading</h2>
        <br />
        <a id="glow-trigger" href="#tomytextbox">Click Me</a>
        <p>this is normal text</p><div data-bind="dxTextBox: {}"></div>

        <div id="tomytextbox">
            <input class="glow" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div data-bind="dxMultiView: { height: 300, items: [{ text: 'Drag me to left' }, { text: 'drag me to right' }] }"></div>
     </div>
```

If I am doing something stupidly wrong, please tell me!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is What you wanted:

**CSS:**

```
.glow:focus { box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(81, 203, 238, 1);
  padding: 3px 0px 3px 3px;
  margin: 5px 1px 3px 0px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(81, 203, 238, 1); }
```

### [Working Fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/51aq3jz8/1/)

**EDIT:**

As you commented it doesn't work on `IOS`

I don't think it's prohibited to do that. Although I think Apple would recommend if it's necessary to mark the selected textfield, you should consider splitting your view into multiple screens. A single screen shouldn't get too cluttered.

However if in your case that's not possible or not wanted, the easiest way to achieve a 'glow-effect' would be this (modify the values as you see fit):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

textField.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
textField.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
textField.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeZero;
textField.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0f;
textField.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
```

(Don't forget to add the Quarz Framework to your project)

It would look like this: 
[image]

Comment: I was just wondering if you could possibly be able to replicate this design, without the movement of the tb? or is this possible?

Comment: @jbutler483 : I didnt understand for what you are looking for?

Comment: it's ok got it sorted - all it was that the textbox was shifting a few pixels when in focus, but managed to do a few tweaks to get it working! thanks :)

Comment: Surprised really - I literally know NOTHING of css/html/typescript!

Comment: I know that site very well-it's more typescript that's hard to understand (i've basically created a typescript project and only used the css and html part! :S

Answer (score 0):

This is how bootstrap 3 does it:

```
.form-control:focus {
    border-color: #66afe9;
    outline: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.075),0 0 8px rgba(102,175,233,.6);
}
```

Why are you using JS when CSS `:focus` does the job?

Comment: I had tried various different approaches, and yet none of the worked for IOS. :(